# How to change the character case in capital and small sequence using jquery

Tags: jquery

Is there any way to generate output like this, first letter is capital and second is small then third is capital and fourth is small and so on:

> Input# Enter Code: **This stackoverflow.com**
>
> Output# You have entered : **ThIs StAcKoVeRfLoW.CoM**

Following are the snippet which i have tried so far.

```js
$("#code").keyup(function(){
  
  var finalCode=$("#code").val();
  for($i=0;$i<=finalCode.length;$i++){
   // finalCode=finalCodeprev[i].toUpper();
    $("#outcode").html(finalCode);  
  }
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Enter Code: <input type="text" name="code" id="code">
<br>
You have enterd : <lable id="outcode"></lable>
```

**Note:This is not capitalize of the word , it is the base on character**

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#code").keyup(function(){
  
  var finalCode=$("#code").val();
  for($i=0;$i<=finalCode.length;$i++){
   // finalCode=finalCodeprev[i].toUpper();
    $("#outcode").html(finalCode);  
  }
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Enter Code: <input type="text" name="code" id="code">
<br>
You have enterd : <lable id="outcode"></lable>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#code").keyup(function(){
  
  var finalCode=$("#code").val();
  for($i=0;$i<=finalCode.length;$i++){
   // finalCode=finalCodeprev[i].toUpper();
    $("#outcode").html(finalCode);  
  }
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Enter Code: <input type="text" name="code" id="code">
<br>
You have enterd : <lable id="outcode"></lable>
```

```
<style>
#outcode{
text-transform: capitalize;

}

</style>
```

Comment: you can also use $('#outcode').css('text-transform','capitalize');

Answer (score 0):

Use **[`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)** method and do something tricky like this

```js
$("#code").on('input', function() {
  var i = 0;
  $("#outcode").html(
    // match all non-space character and replace it with 
    // value of i is odd or even
    this.value.replace(/\S/ig, function(m) {
      // check value is even and increment value ofi
      if (i++ % 2 == 0)
        // convert to upper case
        m = m.toUpperCase();
      // return the replca text
      return m;
    })
  );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Enter Code:
<input type="text" name="code" id="code">
<br>You have enterd :
<lable id="outcode"></lable>
```

Comment: I dont wana "ThIs Is My TeSt" this type of output... first...third...fifth...seventh...character id capital ...

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using regular expressions, I'd suggest instead using simple String, and Array, methods:

```
function alternateCapitals() {
  // retrieving the <input> element's value:
  var text = this.value
             // removing the leading, and trailing, white-space:
             .trim()
             // splitting the String into an Array, with each
             // array-element being a single-character:
             .split('')
             // using Array.prototype.map() to return a
             // modified version of the original characters:
             .map(function(char, index) {
               // char: the first argument, is the current
               // array-element of the array over which
               // we're iterating;
               // index: the second arguement, is the index
               // of the current array-element in the array
               // over which we're iterating.

    // if the remainder of the index divided by 2 is zero we
    // return the character in upper-case, otherwise we return
    // the character in lowercase:
    return index % 2 === 0 ? char.toUpperCase() : char.toLowerCase();

  // we join the Array of characters back together into a string,
  // using Array.prototype.join():
  }).join('');

  // setting the text of the '#outcode' element:
  $('#outcode').text(text);
}

$("#code").keyup(alternateCapitals);
```

```js
function alternateCapitals() {
  var text = this.value.trim().split('').map(function(char, index) {
    return index % 2 === 0 ? char.toUpperCase() : char.toLowerCase();
  }).join('');
  $('#outcode').text(text);
}

$("#code").keyup(alternateCapitals);
```

```css
label {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label>Enter Code:
  <input type="text" name="code" id="code">
</label>
You have entered:
<span id="outcode"></span>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/r58zxLb9/).

References:

- JavaScript:

  - [`Array.prototype.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).
  - [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).
  - [`String.prototype.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).
  - [`String.prototype.trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim).
- jQuery:

  - [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).